# Are ash gourd / winter melon seeds edible?

Tags: vegetables, seeds

I have bought an [ash gourd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_gourd) to use the flesh in various dishes. During preparation I removed, washed and dried the seeds. I couldn't find any trustworthy source on whether or not they are safe or tasty to eat. Are ash gourd / winter melon seeds edible? If so, are they any good and are there any common culinary uses for them?

Comment: When I lived in China I ate them frequently, I am not sure on how they were prepared or else I would make this an answer not a comment.

Comment: As @JCrosby has eaten them, and they're closely related to melons, you could probably try any simple recipe for melon seeds, such as roasting with a tiny bit of oil (I do this with pumpkin seeds when the oven is on anyway). It's important to get all traces of flesh off before cooking and you might need to dry them in a low oven before turning the heat up to get them crispy and ensure they keep. At least as many related species have edible seeds as fruit, which gives further confidence (IMO these 2 comments add up to an answer, and mine is the less important part)